# Why am I getting a figure size plotting error in Python?

Tags: python

My python Code is no longer working.  I messed around with terminal commands (on mac) uninstalling and re installing matplot lib, etc...And think I messed something up.

For this specific problem, code that I know worked before, no longer does.

I have this code where I load in data and plot a fit over it:

```
data = np.loadtxt('peak4.txt', skiprows = 1)

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
nn=len(x)

def f1(x,p0,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    
    return p0*exp(-(x-p1)**2/(2*(p2**2)))+p3*x+p4

pp = 5
guesses = (1,1,1,1,1) 
(p0,p1,p2,p3,p4),cc = curve_fit(f1,x,y,p0=guesses) 
ymod = f1(x,p0,p1,p2,p3,p4)

plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,5))
plt.rc('font', size=16)
plt.plot(x,y,'.b')
plt.plot(x,ymod,'r')
plt.show()

yfit = f1(x,p0,p1,p2,p3,p4)
yys = (yfit-y)**2
chisqr = sum(yys)/(nn-pp)

d = np.sqrt(np.diag(cc))


print(f'Fitting Parameters of f1: p0 = {p0:3.5f}, p1 = {p1:3.5f}, p2 = {p2:3.5f}, p3 = {p3:3.5f}, p4 = {p4:3.5f}')
print(f'\nParameter errors of f1: p0_err = {d[0]:3.5f}, p1_err = {d[1]:3.5f}, p2_err = {d[2]:3.5f}, p3_err = {d[3]:3.5f}, p4_err = {d[4]:3.5f}')
print(f'\nReduced chi-squared for f1: {chisqr:3.5f}')
```

I know for a fact this code worked before.  It was printing a fitted plot, but now the output is just:

```
<Figure size 750x500 with 1 Axes>.
```

Please help

Comment: so you have the same code as before, and you uninstalled some libraries, then why you supposed that posting the code instead of the error message will let us help you to solve the problem?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to create a [mre]. If you are unwilling to provide data, generate some random data that looks similar, see the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I ran part of your script that relates to matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('sample_data.txt', skiprows = 1) #<============ Just to test my sample data

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

ymod = y #<============ Just to test

plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,5))
plt.rc('font', size=16)
plt.plot(x,y,'.b')
plt.plot(x,ymod,'r')
plt.show()
```

It works very well. Output:

[image]

I'd suggest that you run a simple code (removing *curve_fit* function, etc.) to see if your matplotlib works.